# Database dont show relations for two specific entities - spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2, bootstrapping

spent on this over one day and cannot recognize a problem. I don't need perfect solution, just give me instructions were is the problem. Where I can find information about that matter.

I created some entities, some of them you can find below (not all fields, just needed for this task):

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"teams","organizers"})
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String eventName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "event_organizer",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organizer_id"))
    private Set<Organizer> organizers= new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "event_team",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"))
    private Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"events"})
public class Organizer {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String organizerName;
    private String organizerLastName;
    private String organizerEmailAddress;
    private String organizerTelephoneNumber;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "organizers")
    private Set<Event> events= new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"events", "players"})
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String teamName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "team_player",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id"))
    private Set<Player> players = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "teams")
    private Set<Event> events= new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"teams"})
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String playerName;
    private String playerLastName;
    private int playerAge;

    private String playerNickname;
    private String playerEmailAddress;
    private String playerTelephoneNumber;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "players")
    private Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<>();

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private FavouritePosition favouritePosition;
}
```

I have created a bootstrap class which can take data some data from data.sql file:

```
@Component
public class EventBootstrap implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

    //There are some Repositories fields and constructor


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        eventRepository.saveAll(getEvent());
    }

    private List<Event> getEvent() {
        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();


        //Organizers
        Optional<Organizer> ostrouchKolobrzeskaOrganizerOptional = organizerRepository.findByOrOrganizerLastName("Ostrouch");
        if (!ostrouchKolobrzeskaOrganizerOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Organizer not found !");
        }

        Organizer ostrouchKolobrzeskaOrganizer = ostrouchKolobrzeskaOrganizerOptional.get();

        Optional<Organizer> kaimWestFootballPitchOrganizerOptional = organizerRepository.findByOrOrganizerLastName("Kaim");
        if (!kaimWestFootballPitchOrganizerOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Organizer not found!");
        }

        Organizer kaimWestFootballPitchOrganizer = kaimWestFootballPitchOrganizerOptional.get();

        //Set 1 organizers
        Set<Organizer> organizersSetOne = new HashSet<>();
        organizersSetOne.add(kaimWestFootballPitchOrganizer);
        organizersSetOne.add(ostrouchKolobrzeskaOrganizer);


        //Set 2 organizers
        Set<Organizer> organizerSetTwo = new HashSet<>();
        organizerSetTwo.add(ostrouchKolobrzeskaOrganizer);

        //Team
        Optional<Team> jeppesenFootballTeamOptional = teamRepository.findByTeamName("Jeppesen Football Team");
        if (!jeppesenFootballTeamOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Expected football team not found");
        }

        Team jeppesenFootballTeam = jeppesenFootballTeamOptional.get();

        Optional<Team> lufthansaFootballTeamOptional = teamRepository.findByTeamName("Lufthansa Football Team");
        if (!lufthansaFootballTeamOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Expected football team not found");
        }

        Team lufthansaFootballTeam = lufthansaFootballTeamOptional.get();

        //Set 1 team
        Set<Team> teamsSetOne = new HashSet<>();
        teamsSetOne.add(jeppesenFootballTeam);
        teamsSetOne.add(lufthansaFootballTeam);

        //Set 2 team
        Set<Team> teamsSetTwo = new HashSet<>();
        teamsSetTwo.add(lufthansaFootballTeam);

        //getPlayer
        Optional<Player> przemekPlayerOptional = playerRepository.findByPlayerName("Przemyslaw");
        if(!przemekPlayerOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Expected player not found!");
        }

        Optional<Player> jakubPlayerOptional = playerRepository.findByPlayerName("Jakub");
        if(!jakubPlayerOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Expected player not found!");
        }

        Player przemekPlayer = przemekPlayerOptional.get();
        przemekPlayer.setFavouritePosition(FavouritePosition.MIDFIELDER);

        Player jakubPlayer = jakubPlayerOptional.get();
        jakubPlayer.setFavouritePosition(FavouritePosition.ATTACKER);


        Set<Player> playersSetOne = new HashSet<>();
        playersSetOne.add(przemekPlayer);
        playersSetOne.add(jakubPlayer);

        Set<Player> playersSetTwo= new HashSet<>();
        playersSetTwo.add(przemekPlayer);

        //setPlayer for the team
        jeppesenFootballTeam.setPlayers(playersSetOne);
        lufthansaFootballTeam.setPlayers(playersSetTwo);

        Event kolobrzeskaEvent = new Event();
        kolobrzeskaEvent.setOrganizers(organizersSetOne);
        kolobrzeskaEvent.setEventName("Kołobrzeska Event");
        kolobrzeskaEvent.setTeams(teamsSetOne);

        Event westEvent = new Event();
        westEvent.setOrganizers(organizerSetTwo);
        westEvent.setEventName("West Event");
        westEvent.setTeams(teamsSetTwo);

        events.add(kolobrzeskaEvent);
        events.add(westEvent);

        return events;
    }
}
```

It is Spring boot project with thymeleaf and hibernate. When I run the application and look into the H2 database console I have got correct tables: EVENT_ORGANIZER, ORGANIZER, EVENT, PLAYER, TEAM but the TEAM_PLAYER is blank, I dont see any relationship. I tried use debugger, but no effect. Where is the problem? I studied all entities classes and relations looks good, the same with bootstrap class.

If you need any additional information just comment.
Thank you very much for your support

EDIT:
I debugged it one more time, and I noticed that next to some variables I have got exception:

```
Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate java.util.Optional.toString()
```

After that I set fetch = FetchType.EAGER. But the excetion still occurs near jeppesenFootballTeamOptional. Could it be a problem with relations in database?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your data.sql file. The table gets created but data doesn't get inserted. check for ";;" at the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution for this problem!

first of all Bootstrap class update:
I changed Optional and loading small amount od data from a data.sql to creating new Team object in bootstrap class.

```
Team jeppesenFootballTeam = new Team();
    jeppesenFootballTeam.setTeamName("Jeppesen Football Team");
    jeppesenFootballTeam.setPlayers(playersSetTwo);

    Team lufthansaFootballTeam = new Team();
    lufthansaFootballTeam.setTeamName("Lufthasna Football Team");
    lufthansaFootballTeam.setPlayers(playersSetOne);

    Set<Team> teamsSetOne = new HashSet<>();
    teamsSetOne.add(jeppesenFootballTeam);

    Set<Team> teamSetTwo = new HashSet<>();
    teamSetTwo.add(jeppesenFootballTeam);
    teamSetTwo.add(lufthansaFootballTeam);
```

Second problem with 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' solved by adding a "fetch = FetchType.EAGER" to relation annotation for Player and Organizer class (class which we use Optional to create object by data.sql).

At the end I forgot about one important thing adding a cascade type to the Parent:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "event_team",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"))
    private Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<>();
```

I would like to add that problems occurs when we would like to load some data from data.sql and additionaly we would like to set some properties in bootstrap class.

This is complete solution for my problems. I hope it will help someone else, thanks !